# How to use the monitor / mwait instructions in x86-64 assembly on Mac or baremetal

Tags: macos, events, assembly, x86-64

*Originally I asked about umonitor and umwait, but it turns out as @harold suggested, that you can't even buy a processor that has those instructions yet. So this question is about monitor and mwait, because I am interested how to use those on baremetal.*

---

I just learned of [monitor](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/monitor)/[mwait](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait).

I would have thought that there would be no evaluation of any instructions once `mwait` is called, so I don't understand how other parts of memory could be written to. Unless perhaps this is some multithreaded stuff with shared memory of some sort, which I don't fully think I understand.

Wondering if one could whip up a quick hello world program to demonstrate how to use these instructions. My attempt at it is this.

```
global _main

section .text

_main:
  call print1
  ; watch when address 1000
  ; (randomly chosen)
  ; is written to.
  mov eax, 1000
  monitor eax
  ; wait for 100 ms, not sure
  ; or some interrupt
  mov eax, 100
  mwait eax
  call print2
  call exit

print2:
  mov rdx, msg2.len
  mov rsi, msg2
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rax, 0x2000004
  syscall
  ret

print1:
  mov rdx, msg1.len
  mov rsi, msg1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rax, 0x2000004
  syscall
  ret

exit:
  mov rdi, 0 ; exit status
  mov rax, 0x2000001 ;: exit
  syscall

section .data
msg1: db "start", 0xa, 0
.len: equ $ - msg1
msg2: db "end", 0xa, 0
.len: equ $ - msg2
```

What I'm wondering is what an example usage looks like for (a) a timespan like 100ms delay, and/or (b) an "event" of writing to a specific part of memory to trigger the callback, and/or (c) an external event like keyboard interrupt or ctrl+c interrupt if there is such a thing. Or perhaps the timing thing is done with [`tpause`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tpause).

Trying the following with `tpause` I get `error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`:

```
mov eax, 1000
mov edx, 1000
mov rdi, 0
tpause rdi, edx, eax
```

The few resources I've found:

- https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf
- https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-303.html
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-the-monitor-and-mwait-streaming-simd-extensions-3-instructions
- http://blog.andy.glew.ca/2010/11/httpsemipublic.html

Comment: Your CPU does not support `tpause`  and `umwait`, you cannot even buy a processor that supports those yet

Comment: Then an explanation of how to use `monitor` and `mwait` would be helpful, for baremetal. Updated the question to focus on that.

Comment: As specified in the manual, the first operand to `tpause` must be a 32 bit register.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait#example describes what the operands mean for monitor/mwait.  (They're implicit, in EAX, ECX and EDX.)