# Working example of UMONITOR/UMWAIT-based assembly (asm) spin-wait loops as a replacement for PAUSE-based test-test-and-set loops

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, thread-synchronization, spinlock

In the *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual*, Intel gives an example of a PAUSE-based spin-wait loop ("Example 11-4. Spin-wait Loop and PAUSE Instruction").

However, as for the UMONITOR/UMWAIT instruction, there are only mentions without any example ("Support for user level low-power and low-latency spin-loop instructions UMWAIT/UMONITOR and TPAUSE", and "UMWAIT/UMONITOR/TPAUSE instructions enable power savings in user level spin loops"). These new instructions came out with the Tremont Microarchitecture, released by Intel on September 2020 within the Elkhart Lake platform.

Can you please give a working example, on the assembly language, of *SpinWaitAndAquireLock* and *ReleaseLock* functions that use a byte value as a synchronization variable (in either 64-bit or 32-bit addressing mode), so that this byte can be only in one of the two states, i.e., contain just two values: `cLockByteLocked` (e.g., `0FFh`) and `cLockByteAvailable` (e.g., `0`)!? I can give such functions using the PAUSE instruction as a reference example, that can be compiled by `nasm -f win64`:

```
section .text

; This code exposes two global functions: (1) SpinWaitAndAquireLock; (2) ReleaseLock.


cLockByteLocked     equ 0FFh
cLockByteAvailable  equ 0

; wait for the byte to not be locked and lock it
global SpinWaitAndAquireLock

; release lock obtained previously by SpinWaitAndAquireLock
global ReleaseLock

SpinWaitAndAquireLock:
; input: rcx - address of the synchronization variable lock byte
   mov  eax, cLockByteLocked ; load the value that denotes "locked" into al; use eax to clear remaining bits to avoid false dependency on existing eax value, bits 32-63 of rax are also cleared
   jmp  @FirstCompare
@NormalLoadLoop:
   pause  
@FirstCompare:
; use the "test, test-and-set" technique
   cmp  [rcx], al   ; try normal load first instead of the locked load - "test" is a first part of "test, test-and-set"
   je   @NormalLoadLoop ; for static branch prediction, jump backward means "likely"
   lock xchg [rcx], al  ; since normal load shows the synchronization variable is available, try locked load and store ("test-and-set")
   cmp  al, cLockByteLocked
   je   @NormalLoadLoop
   ret

ReleaseLock:
; input: rcx - address of the synchronization variable lock byte
   mov   byte [rcx], cLockByteAvailable ; just use normal store
   ret
```

Comment: The vol.2 entry for `mwait` has pseudo-code for an example: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait#example .  It looks appropriate for `umonitor` / `umwait`, too, basically replacing `pause` in the spin loop.  You still check the memory location on wake because spurious wake is possible, but hopefully you sleep until another core has stored to the location you set up a monitor on.  Some other links in [How to use the monitor / mwait instructions in x86-64 assembly on Mac or baremetal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55296528) might be relevant.

Comment: @PeterCordes - can you please still write a small code that works? I saw the pseudocode but I was not sure whether I understood it correctly. However, the code that you referred at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296528/how-to-use-the-monitor-mwait-instructions-in-x86-64-assembly-on-mac-or-baremet is helpful, I will try to adapt it for umwait/umonitor.

Comment: I don't have hardware to test on, so I'm reluctant to post an answer.  If SDM supports it somehow (probably "waking up" / timing out immediately) that might be better than nothing.  It seems fairly trivial to use, though, and `umonitor` and `umwait` both clearly documented (that's the other part of what makes me not want to take the time to write up an example).  Is there any specific part you aren't sure you've understood.

Comment: I have the hardware, @PeterCordes (a remote Linux server with i5 12th Gen). I will make a code and share it here and let you know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PeterCordes - do you have an idea on why CPUID returns two values: one for the smallest and another one for the largest monitor-line size in bytes? In my case, both values are the same - 64 bytes. Can you speculate on why different sizes may encounter and why they both may be needed?

Comment: I haven't checked the manuals, but it might be a similar idea to `std::hardware_constructive_interference_size` and `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) - the size limit where you definitely will get notified of a change, and the largest size where you *might* get woken up by a store nearby, so put other data at least <the larger size> away to avoid spurious wakeups.  The fact that current HW works on single cache lines isn't surprising, but it's smart to leave room for different future designs.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I implemented the instructions in https://github.com/maximmasiutin/FastMM4-AVX and they gain significant benefit when the number of virtual threads used by the program exceeds the number of physical threads provided by the CPU; therwise there is no benefit. In the FastMM4-AVX, for Linux on a 12-thread CPU with 64 logical threads, the program with umonitor/umwait implementation is 6(!) times faster than one of "pause", the benchmark code is at Tests/Benchmarks/Realloc.dpr.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, on the assembly language, of SpinWaitAndAquireLock and ReleaseLock functions that use a byte value as a synchronization variable in 64-bit mode. This example can be compiled by `nasm` with the `-f win64` parameter. It is adapted from https://github.com/maximmasiutin/FastMM4-AVX/blob/master/FastMM4.pas

The functions in this example use Microsoft's Win64 "x64 ABI" calling convention, i.e., the example works under Windows without modification. In this calling convention, first parameter is passed in the `rcx` register. If you wish to use this example under Linux (where the "System V AMD64 ABI" calling convention is used and the first parameter is passed in the `rdi` register), replace `rcx' with 'rdi'.

The umonitor/umwait in this example give significant benefit when the number of virtual threads used by the program exceeds the number of physical threads provided by the CPU; otherwise there is no benefit. In the FastMM4-AVX, for Linux on a 12-thread CPU with 64 logical threads, the program with umonitor/umwait implementation is 6(!) times faster than one of "pause", the benchmark code is at Tests/Benchmarks/Realloc.dpr in the FastMM repository.

In this example, the "test, test-and-set" technique is used for the spin-wait loops; this technique is recommended by Intel (see Section 11.4.3 "Optimization with Spin-Locks" of the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual) to determine the availability of the synchronization variable; according to this technique, the first "test" is done via the normal (non-locking) memory load to prevent excessive bus locking on each iteration of the spin-wait loop; if the variable is available upon the normal memory load of the first step ("test"), proceed to the second step ("test-and-set") which is done via the bus-locking atomic "xchg" instruction; however, this two-steps approach of using "test" before "test-and-set" can increase the cost for the uncontented case comparing to just single-step "test-and-set", this may explain why the speed benefits of this approach which are more pronounced when the code called from multiple threads in parallel (in very contended scenarios), while in single-threaded use scenario there may be no benefit or even slight speed degradation.

```
; Copyright attribution: code taken from the repository github.com/maximmasiutin/FastMM4-AVX - see that repository for details.

; wait for the byte to not be locked and lock it
global SpinWaitAndAquireLock

; release lock obtained previously by SpinWaitAndAquireLock
global ReleaseLock


cLockByteLocked     equ 109
cLockByteAvailable  equ 0
cUMWaitTime         equ 7000000

SpinWaitAndAquireLock:
; input: rcx - address of the synchronization variable lock byte
   mov  r8, cLockByteLocked
   cmp  [rcx], r8b
   je   @LockMonitor
   mov  eax, r8
   xchg [rcx], al
   cmp  al, cLockByteLocked
   je   @LockMonitor
   jmp  @Finish

@DidntLockUmonitor:
   cmp  [rcx], r8b
   jne  @TryXchgAfterUmonitor

@LockMonitor:
   umonitor rcx
   cmp  [rcx], r8b
   jne  @TryXchgAfterUmonitor

   mov  eax, cUMWaitTime
   xor  edx, edx ; this also clears bits 32-61, but this is irrelevant since umwait uses eax/edx

;       bit[0] = 0  C0.2: wakeup time: slower; power savings: larger; other benefits: improves performance of the other SMT thread(s) on the same core.
;       bit[0] = 1  C0.1: wakeup time: faster; power savings: smaller; ther benefits: NA
   xor  r9d, r9d ; this also clears bit 32-61, but this is irrelevant since umwait only uses bits 0-31

   umwait r9d

@TryXchgAfterUmonitor:
   mov  eax, r8
   xchg [rcx], al
   cmp  al, cLockByteLocked
   je   @DidntLockUmonitor
; Locked after umonitor

@Finish:
   ret


ReleaseLock:
; input: rcx - address of the synchronization variable lock byte
   mov   byte [rcx], cLockByteAvailable ; just use normal, store rather than locked store
   ret
```

Comment: Normally you'd want to try the first `xchg` before running `umonitor`; no need for that instruction in the fast-path case where the lock is available.  Also, in most use-cases (where contention is usually not extreme), you want the first access to be the atomic RMW so this core does a read-for-ownership, instead of first a share-request then an RFO to promote from MESI Shared to MESI Exclusive.  [Which method is more efficient: retry TAS(), or spin read-only on test()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/76012489) / [Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure?](//stackoverflow.com/q/63008857)

Comment: Is there a function entry-point anywhere in this code block?  At the first `jmp`?  You could make `@TryXchgAfterUmonitor:` the function entry point so the fast path involves no taken branches, after adjusting the rest of the code. (And yes, you can put code before the function entry point; as far as linkers are concerned, that other code might as well be a helper function you tailcall.)  Or maybe duplicate the xchg since on failure you want to run `umonitor`, but only the first time.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, I added `SpinWaitAndAquireLock:`

Comment: `SpinWaitAndAquireLock` branches to `@FirstLockMonitor` which uses `al` but it seems you didn't initialise `al`? Is this intended, am I mistaken?

Comment: Thank, and sorry, I didn't fully copied the code. Now it seems OK.

Comment: `xchg` has an implicit `lock` prefix (except maybe on 286 or earlier).  `lock xchg` is a waste of code size.  Also, this still does a read-only check before taking the lock, so you'll probably get two off-core transactions when the lock is available but was last unlocked by another core. It might be better with extreme contention, but hopefully most real use cases aren't that.  Or is avoiding extra RFOs important for `umwait`?

Comment: I know that lock xchg is a waste of code, but it increases the readability of code; I will remove it if you wish. As about the read, yes, it is optimized for highly-contented scenarios, because on lower-contented it is anyway fast.

Comment: @PeterCordes - with this approach, when the contention is high, we first check with normal read to not polute the bus with locks if it is already locked.

Comment: @PeterCordes - to be specific, here I used the "test, test-and-set" technique for the spin-wait loops; this technique is recommended by Intel (see Section 11.4.3 "Optimization with Spin-Locks" of the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual) to determine the availability of the synchronization variable; according to this technique, the first "test" is done via the normal (non-locking) memory load to prevent excessive bus locking on each iteration of the spin-wait loop

Comment: I edited the answer and made a clarification. Can you please review?

Comment: Ok, yes if you're intentionally optimizing for the high-contention case at the expense of the best case.  (Which I guess is where `umwait` is most useful). Looks good, although `jmp  @Finish` should just be a `ret`, which is smaller and keeps the fast path contiguous.  `cmp  [rcx], al` is indeed optimal, unlike cmp-immediate it allows micro + macro-fusion of the cmp/jcc.  `cmp  al, cLockByteLocked` would normally be `test al,al` to check for any non-zero, but `cmp al, 109` is still only 2 bytes since you're using AL with byte operand-size.

Comment: You could avoid redoing the `mov  eax, cLockByteLocked` before every `xchg` if you used a different register (but not EDX:EAX because they're used by `umwait`.)  So I guess R8D / R8B?  Either `xchg` loads R8b=0 and we got the lock, or it loaded `cLockByteLocked`.  The data dependency between the xchg load and the next xchg store is not a problem; we're pausing (or `umwait`ing) anyway.  That costs a REX prefix on each `xchg`, and `cmp` if you use it, unfortunately, but prob. still saves total code size.  x86-64 SysV has CL and ESI available.

Comment: `xor  rdx, rdx` should be `xor edx,edx`,    `xor  r9, r9` should be `xor r9d, r9d`.
.  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)

Comment: I guess that some opcodes with al are shorter, isnt' it?

Comment: OK, let me do the optimizations that you suggested.

Comment: In your code, `cmp  al, cLockByteLocked` is the only instruction that's shorter because you used AL instead of CL.  `test cl,cl` would still be 2 bytes, if you don't mind treating any non-0 byte as locked.  So an x86-64 SysV version would get pure savings.  But R8B would cost a REX prefix on every `xchg` and `cmp`, probably still coming out slightly smaller, but definitely fewer uops.

Comment: isn't xchg with al also shorter?

Comment: xchg is only shorter with al/ax/eax and another register, not with memory

Comment: `mov  eax, r8` won't even assemble, mismatched operand-size.  You want 5-byte `mov eax, cLockByteLocked` + 3-byte `mov r8d, eax` early in the function.  Not 7-byte `mov r8, sign_extended_imm32` (if your assembler doesn't optimize the operand-size to 32-bit for you like NASM does.)  Also, you missed replacing `jmp  @Finish` (2 bytes) with `ret` (1 byte) which also saves dynamic instruction count and helps I-cache / uop-cache locality for the fast-path.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/MhnEE9s6E is an optimized version.  48 bytes of machine code, down from 59.  So no savings if you `align 16` after `ReleaseLock` but not between `SpinWaitAndAquireLock` and  `ReleaseLock`; either way rounds up to 64 total.  I took out the `@DidntLockUmonitor` test; it's only reached if `xchg` just failed, seems too early to try again without even a `pause`.  Likely to just generate useless coherency traffic.  So don't check again until after `umonitor`.  (Do we need to run `umonitor` ahead of every `umwait`?  Probably yes; a context switch could destroy our monitor.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/EWc58cYfq is 1 byte larger but fewer uops (just using R8B everywhere, not AL), and hoists EDX:EAX setup out of the retry loop since `umonitor` only reads it.  It might only run from legacy decode anyway, with 3 microcoded instructions in the same 32-byte block plus other things.  It might be worth checking CF after `umwait` to see if the OS-limited deadline expired, and if so only checking read-only instead of `xchg`.  Also, the low byte of the EAX TSC count could be the lock byte value, getting us down to 37 bytes: https://godbolt.org/z/dGPdPxvYh (41 total with unlock)

Comment: @PeterCordes - can you please edit the post to improve it, because I didn't fully understand the changes in detail. Although I understand them as a whole to decrease size of code or number of microops or speed, I afraid I could incorrectly introduce your changes and comments, however, could you please keep the whole test, test-and-set" technique, i.e. keep the test before umonitor?

Comment: My version does still test before test-and-set.  There's no path that reaches an `xchg` without having checked right before that with a pure load.  `umonitor` runs right after a failed `xchg`.  There seems no point in running a `cmp/jcc` between those two things.  I also don't have a CPU with WAITPKG to test this on, you do, so you should be able to copy/paste my code exactly.  It's intended to be a drop-in replacement, using the same calling convention.  If you want to include the 37-byte version in your answer, I'd recommend showing the more-flexible version answer first.

Comment: (Correction, the other way `umonitor` can be reached is via a failed `cmp` after a read-only check on function entry.)  `umonitor` doesn't write the cache line, neither does `umwait`, they just take time.  And we check read-only between `umonitor` and `umwait`.  Anyway, checking read-only right after checking with `xchg` serves no purpose.  Very likely the lock is still locked, and in a high-contention situation we're just interfering with other cores checking, or with the lock holder unlocking.

Comment: I experienced that umwait does not guarantee that the memory changed even if we used correct padding, it may be about 30 exits from umwait without any memmory change until an actual change occurs, I did tests, therefore, on highly contented code reading after umwait did bring performance benefit in the code that I referred to.

Comment: Oh, so even the highest timeout allowed by the OS wasn't enough. Or I guess more likely other cores woke at about the same time due to a change in the memory location, and only one of them can win the race to take the lock at that point.  And perhaps an unnecessary write would lead to spurious wakeups for cores that are monitoring coherence traffic for this cache line.

Comment: But your current code doesn't check read-only after `umwait`, it first tries an `xchg` *then* checks read-only if that fails.  That's the part that doesn't seem useful to me, read-only right after an atomic RMW.  It could make sense to check after `umwait` before `xchg`, but is there some reason it makes sense to check after, before umonitor/umwait?

Comment: Thank you again for pointing that out, I don't remember exactly about that particular instruction, but most likely I intentionaly did this way based on my microbenchmarking, i.e. this decision on my particular scenario showed better results, I've used https://github.com/maximmasiutin/FastCodeBenchmark -- however, you are most probably right, and in some if not most other contents your way may work better. This is all very particular. I've noticed that the decision to use this instruction at all gave very big benefit on very high contention, other changes were minor.